# ActiveHash with negation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class:

```
class Foo < ActiveHash::Base
  ...
end
```

I want to query for the negation on some property. If it were a subclass of `ActiveRecord`, then it is possible to do:

```
Foo.where.not(some_property: ["foo", "bar"])
```

But this raises an error for `ActiveHash`. How can I do this?

Comment: Looking at this https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash/blob/master/lib/active_hash/base.rb, there is no not method defined and seems it is not following the activeRecord query method chain. You need to do it by getting all records and selecting what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well this line should work, can you submit the error that you are receiving?